# ORA-12714: invalid national character set specified

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

I got a problem with oracle database ,i created a stored procedure and i wanted to pass an array of items' ids to this procedure to select the data according to array of items using "in" clause,the available solution to this as i found was to create a function and pass a string value with all item's ids seperated by a comma ,and this function will return a datatble with a row for each item id.this approach works fine when i try it in toad in a select statement,,but when i use it in the stored procedure i get a strange error

"ORA-12714: invalid national character set specified"

after searching about the reason of that error i found that it is a bug in that version of oracle according to this page and it was fixed in a 10.2.0.4 oracle patch and the exact reason is to declare a cursor for the function that returns a data table

As it is impossible to me to let the users who work on a live production environment to stop the servers to apply the update patch ,I was wondering if any Oracle expert can help me to declare a cursor and return that cursor instead of returning the table.

my Oracle function,Thanks in Advance

```
create or replace

FUNCTION SplitIDs(
      v_List IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN RtnValue_Set PIPELINED
  AS
    SWV_List VARCHAR2(2000);
    v_RtnValue Dt_RtnValue := Dt_RtnValue(NULL);
  BEGIN
    SWV_List                  := v_List;
    WHILE (instr(SWV_List,',') > 0)
    LOOP
      FOR RetRow                                               IN
      (SELECT ltrim(rtrim(SUBSTR(SWV_List,1,instr(SWV_List,',') -1))) SelectedValue
      FROM dual
      )
      LOOP
        v_RtnValue.SelectedValue := RetRow.SelectedValue;
        PIPE ROW(v_RtnValue);
      END LOOP;
      SWV_List := SUBSTR(SWV_List,instr(SWV_List,',')+LENGTH(','),LENGTH(SWV_List));
    END LOOP;
    FOR RetRow IN
    (SELECT ltrim(rtrim(SWV_List)) SelectedValue FROM dual
    )
    LOOP
      v_RtnValue.SelectedValue := RetRow.SelectedValue;
      PIPE ROW(v_RtnValue);
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
  END;
```

Comment: This is a complicated way to split a comma-separated string into a series of tokens.  Check out this simpler way of achieving the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142665/how-to-convert-csv-to-table-in-oracle/3142795#3142795

Comment: Thanks a lot that works fine.i am new to Oracle,to i created it in T-Sql and used a converter tool and converted it to PL-Sql

Answer (score 2):

Oracle says this about the error:

Error:    ORA-12714  (ORA-12714)

Text:     invalid national character set specified

Cause:  Only UTF8 and AL16UTF16 are allowed to be used as the national character set

Action: Ensure that the specified national character set is valid

Check your  NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET which is set using:

select value from NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS where parameter = 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET';

Try using NCHAR, NVARCHAR2 or NCLOB