# sql - single query to return values that are not present

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

For example, you have a simple table with just one column.
ie.

```
CREATE TABLE movies   (title VARCHAR2(255 BYTE))
```

set up with the following data:

```
INSERT INTO movies   (title) VALUES ('Scream');
INSERT INTO movies   (title) VALUES ('Blair Witch');
INSERT INTO movies   (title) VALUES ('Friday the 13th');
INSERT INTO movies   (title) VALUES ('Scary Movie');
INSERT INTO movies   (title) VALUES ('Hide and Seek');
INSERT INTO movies   (title) VALUES ('Alien vs Predator');
```

Is there a single query or PL/SQL that will do the following dynamically (ie without having to manually do a "UNION select 'scream' from dual..." for every value)?

Obviously this query is wrong but you get the idea:

```
Select * from movies
where title in (
'Scream',
'Scary Movie',
'Exorcist',
'Dracula',
'Saw',
'Hide and Seek'
)
```

Desired result being a record for every value in the "WHERE TITLE IN" clause where the record is not present in the table.
ie.

```
'Exorcist'
'Dracula'
'Saw'
```

Comment: Selected rows all ways come from a relation (table). You must create a table at some moment, probably with "UNION select 'scream' from dual..." for every value like you were saying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using 10g or higher, you can build a function which converts a CSV string into a  dynamic table.  Check out the code for a string tokenizer in [this other response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142665/how-to-convert-csv-to-table-in-oracle/3142795#3142795).

You would use it like this:

```
select * from movies
where title NOT in (
         select * 
          from table (string_tokenizer
                      (
                          'Scream, Scary Movie,Exorcist,Dracula,Saw,Hide and Seek'
                        )

                  )
     )
/
```

---

Here is a slightly simpler implementation which doesn't require any additional infrastructure:

```
SQL> select * from table(sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll('Scream',
'Scary Movie',
'Exorcist',
'Dracula',
'Saw',
'Hide and Seek'
 ))
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8  
COLUMN_VALUE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Scream
Scary Movie
Exorcist
Dracula
Saw
Hide and Seek

6 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is similar to [the Table Value Constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8007821/sql-single-query-to-return-values-that-are-not-present/8009894#8009894), but it does only work for single column "tables".

Comment: The keyword `table` and the name `sys.dbms_debug_vc2coll` were what I was looking for. Helped me avoid repeating `union select` multiple times. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the ***"Table Value Constructors"*** feature. I don't think Oracle supports that.

See the article of Joe Celko about: **[Table Value Constructors in SQL Server 2008](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-training/table-value-constructors-in-sql-server-2008/)** amd an example taken from there:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( VALUES
      (101, 'Bikes'),
      (102, 'Accessories'),
      (103, 'Clothes')
  ) AS Category(CategoryID, CategoryName);
```

Comment: shame oracle does not have this

Comment: I think DB2 has it, too. And SQL-Server only at latest (2008) versions.

Comment: I would add that SOME versions of DB2 have this.  I use v7r4 and later pretty heavily and it does support it.  Some of the older machines (v5), though ... not so much.

Comment: @Meower68 not sure if that info should be an edit. Out of curiousity, does DB2 (the version you use) support this (query without SELECT): `VALUES
      (101, 'Bikes'),
      (102, 'Accessories'),
      (103, 'Clothes') ;` (Postgres does)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a table type and the function table() to cast a list to a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE varchar_list_type as table of varchar2(100);

CREATE OR REPLACE function in_varchar_list ( p_string in varchar2 ) return varchar_list_type
as
    l_data             varchar_list_type := varchar_list_type();
    l_string           long default p_string || ',';
    l_n                number;
begin

    loop
        exit when l_string is null;

        l_data.extend;
        l_n := instr( l_string, ',' );
        l_data( l_data.count ) := substr( l_string, 1, l_n-1 );
        l_string := substr( l_string, l_n+1 );

    end loop;
    return l_data;
end;
```

Then use like this:

```
select * from TABLE(select cast(in_varchar_list('foo,bar,baz') as varchar_list_type) from dual)
```

Ofcourse you can use a bind variable or a normal variable instead of hardcoded string 'foo,bar,baz'.

edit: typo in the query ^_^"