# Display value from list even if record doesn't exist in the database

Tags: oracle

I have this odd case where I'd like to display all list values with i.e. counter
My test table content

```
name, misc
A, blah
B, 123
A, asd
```

now, this query will fetch results just for A and B, but how can I display C "results"

```
select name, count(*) from table 
where name in ('A','B','C')
```

result I'd like to get

```
A 2
B 1
C 0
```

this case is driving me mad for a day already.
please help

Cheers,
      Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to use an outer join for this type of query, such as:

```
WITH mylist AS (SELECT 'A' name FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL SELECT 'B' FROM DUAL
                UNION ALL SELECT 'C' FROM DUAL)
SELECT l.name, COUNT(t.name)
  FROM mylist l
  LEFT JOIN mytable t ON l.name = t.name
 GROUP BY l.name
```

You could use a table object instead of a UNION ALL:

```
CREATE TYPE name_list_t AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(30);
/

SELECT l.name, COUNT(t.name)
  FROM (SELECT column_value name FROM TABLE(name_list_t('A', 'B', 'C')) l
  LEFT JOIN mytable t ON l.name = t.name
 GROUP BY l.name
```

Comment: another masterpiece by Vincent! cheers. as I don't want to create new table option 1 is what I was looking for. artificial +1 for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by outer joining a table containing your list of values:

```
WITH lookup AS (
SELECT decode(LEVEL
             ,1,'A'
             ,2,'B'
             ,3,'C') col1
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
)
,test AS (
SELECT decode(LEVEL
             ,1,'A'
             ,2,'A'
             ,3,'B') col1
     ,decode(LEVEL
             ,1,'blah'
             ,2,'123'
             ,3,'asd') col2        
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3
) 
SELECT lookup.col1,count(test.col1)
  FROM lookup
      ,test
 WHERE lookup.col1 = test.col1 (+)
GROUP BY lookup.col1
;
```

Returns:

```
A   2
B   1
C   0
```

In my example "lookup" is generated on the fly. You can either use this approach or most probably better use your own list of values table.

Answer (score 0):

get a splitter function from here: [how to convert csv to table in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3142665/319875)

and then

```
select a.column_value, count(t.name) 
from table(splitter('A,B,C')) a
left join table t on (t.name = a.column_value)
group by a.column_value
```