# Extended opposite listagg

Tags: sql, string, oracle, csv, tokenize

I noticed some question regarding how to 'unlistagg' but so far i could not find something meet my requirement below. 
Sorry if i missed out some good answer in the past.

I have data like below:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Title   | column_A     | column_B        | column_c        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3007576 | 1000         | 0               | 3000             |
| 3007879 | 100,200,300  |                 | 400,500         |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

but I would like to display them in:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
| Title   | column_A     | column_B        | column_c        |
--------------------------------------------------------------
| 3007576 | 1000         | 0               | 3000            |
| 3007879 | 100          |                 | 400             |
| 3007879 | 100          |                 | 500             |
| 3007879 | 200          |                 | 400             |
| 3007879 | 200          |                 | 500             |
| 3007879 | 300          |                 | 400             |
| 3007879 | 300          |                 | 500             |
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189575/listunagg-function

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your data is that there are three columns and they can be nullable or vary in length. So you can do three subqueries (where left join is important, to not loose any row) at first, then again left join data. To split strings I used `xmltable` way, you can use any other method already described on SO.

```
-- sample data
with t(title, column_A, column_B, column_c) as (
    select 3007576, '1000', '0', '3000' from dual union all
    select 3007879, '100, 200,300', null, '400,500' from dual union all
    select 3007900, null, '80, 205, 212', '54, 5417' from dual )
-- end of sample data
select *
  from (
    select title, trim(column_value) ca from t 
      left join xmltable(('"' || replace(column_a, ',', '","') || '"')) on 1 = 1) a
  left join (
    select title, trim(column_value) cb from t 
      left join xmltable(('"' || replace(column_b, ',', '","') || '"')) on 1 = 1) b 
  using (title)
  left join (
    select title, trim(column_value) cc from t 
      left join xmltable(('"' || replace(column_c, ',', '","') || '"')) on 1 = 1) c 
  using (title)
  order by title, ca, cb, cc
```

Result for my data:

```
TITLE    CA    CB    CC
-------- ----- ----- -----
 3007576 1000  0     3000
 3007879 100         400
 3007879 100         500
 3007879 200         400
 3007879 200         500
 3007879 300         400
 3007879 300         500
 3007900       205   54
 3007900       205   5417
 3007900       212   54
 3007900       212   5417
 3007900       80    54
 3007900       80    5417
```