# splitting two columns containing comma separated values in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two columns in a table with comma separated values, how do it split it into rows?

Comment: there are lots of options out there, [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14328621/splitting-string-into-multiple-rows-in-oracle)

Comment: @micklesh Partly yes, but the issue is i have two  columns with comma separated value in a single table , how can i split them?

Comment: a simplest (but INCORRECT) option - combine the 2 columns into a single value and consider that concatenated field. or treat the fields separately and combine the results afterwards

Comment: Provide test case with ddl,table data and expected output.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13189575/listunagg-function) help? "listunagg function"

Comment: The correct solution is to fix the data model. Don't store delimited data in a column

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
SQL> with test (col1, col2) as
  2    (select 'Little,Foot,is,stupid', 'poor,bastard'         from dual union all
  3     select 'Green,mile,is,a'      , 'good,film,is,it,not?' from dual
  4    )
  5  select regexp_substr(col1 ||','|| col2, '[^,]+', 1, column_value) str
  6  from test cross join
  7       table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
  8                           connect by level <= regexp_count(col1 ||','|| col2, ',') + 1
  9                          ) as sys.odcinumberlist));

STR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Little
Foot
is
stupid
poor
bastard
Green
mile
is
a
good
film
is
it
not?

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive sub-query factoring clause and simple string functions:

```sql
WITH splits ( id, c1, c2, idx, start_c1, end_c1, start_c2, end_c2 ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         c1,
         c2,
         1,
         1,
         INSTR( c1, ',', 1 ),
         1,
         INSTR( c2, ',', 1 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         c1,
         c2,
         idx + 1,
         CASE end_c1 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE end_c1 + 1 END,
         CASE end_c1 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE INSTR( c1, ',', end_c1 + 1 ) END,
         CASE end_c2 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE end_c2 + 1 END,
         CASE end_c2 WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE INSTR( c2, ',', end_c2 + 1 ) END
  FROM   splits
  WHERE  end_c1 > 0
  OR     end_c2 > 0
)
SELECT id,
       idx,
       CASE end_c1
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( c1, start_c1 )
       ELSE SUBSTR( c1, start_c1, end_c1 - start_c1 )
       END AS c1,
       CASE end_c2
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( c2, start_c2 )
       ELSE SUBSTR( c2, start_c2, end_c2 - start_c2 )
       END AS c2
FROM   splits s
ORDER BY id, idx;
```

So for the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_data ( id, c1, c2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'a,b,c,d', 'e,f,g' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'h', 'i' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, 'j,k,l,m,n' FROM DUAL;
```

This outputs:

> ```
> ID | IDX | C1   | C2  
> -: | --: | :--- | :---
>  1 |   1 | a    | e   
>  1 |   2 | b    | f   
>  1 |   3 | c    | g   
>  1 |   4 | d    | null
>  2 |   1 | h    | i   
>  3 |   1 | null | j   
>  3 |   2 | null | k   
>  3 |   3 | null | l   
>  3 |   4 | null | m   
>  3 |   5 | null | n
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c03846e4110dfe14f548f27cd42182a)*

Comment: any simpler way

Comment: @VinodNM What you are asking is not "simple" so you are not going to find an easy one-line answer. This answer is pretty "simple" .... it just iterates over the strings finding commas in the recursive sub-query factoring clause and then in the bottom section finds the substrings between those commas. There are plenty of "other" ways including regular expressions, using self-joins to table collection expressions or custom functions but this is possibly one of the more "efficient" ways as it does not involve context switches to PL/SQL that a custom function would nor any joins.